# array.length-1 returns NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to remove the last item from an array, but it's not working. I did some debugging and found that array.length-1 was returning NaN for some reason. Oddly enough, array.length (without the -1) worked just fine.

```
lettersA.splice(lettersA.length-1);
```

Any answers? (I'm using p5 in case that helps at all)

Comment: What is the real length? And the type of it?

Comment: You need to add second parameter as 1

Comment: You can use negative index to indicate count from last like `lettersA.splice(-1,1);` or if its just a single element `lettersA.pop();` `lettersA.splice(lettersA.length-1);` should also work though.

Comment: And what exactly returns `NaN`, your debugging, which we can't see? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: The `NaN` implies Not a Number - is lettersA definitely an array and *not* an object?

Comment: I figured out the problem - I had keyTyped adding the key last typed to the array, which happened to also be adding the key used to splice it - I simply added an if statement to it checking to see if any key other than the delete key is being pressed. I also used lettersA.pop() instead of splice. Code: (I was using space (keyCode 32) as the delete key) `function keyTyped () {
if(keyCode!==16&&keyCode!==127&&keyCode!==32&&typingA===true) {
lettersA.push(key);
}
if (keyCode===32&&typingA===true&&deleteDelay<=0) {
lettersA.pop();
deleteDelay = 10;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) in this way actually works because the `start` parameter is the last item, and since you've omitted the `deleteCount` parameter it will remove everything from `start` to the end of the array - the last item.

I think that the NaN you describe is cause by the return value of Array#slice. Slice returns an **array** that contains the deleted element(s), and you're probably trying to use this array as a number.

Example:

```js
var lettersA = ['angel', 'clown', 'mandarin', 'sturgeon'];

console.log("removed element: ", lettersA.splice(lettersA.length-1));

console.log("Array: ", lettersA);
```

If you want to get the removed value use [Array#pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop). Array#pop returns the removed element, without wrapping it in an array.

Example:

```js
var lettersA = ['angel', 'clown', 'mandarin', 'sturgeon'];

console.log("Removed element :", lettersA.pop());

console.log("Array: ", lettersA);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Volem said, you are missing the second parameter of `splice` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)).

You can also just use `pop` if you are only removing one element from the end of the array ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop))

Comment: The rest of the [arguments are optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Parameters), though.

Comment: @Teemu They are optional, but if he wants to delete the last element, it might be a little challenging without providing the `deleteCount`.

Comment: @eqwert - no it's not - "If deleteCount is omitted, or if its value is larger than array.length - start, then all of the elements beginning with start index on through the end of the array will be deleted."

Comment: @OriDrori Ah fair enough :) My mistake